# Plotting a simple flower

Tags: plot, octave

I need to make ellipses go around a circle to make a flower, i've gotten pretty close to the solution but I don't know how to fix it, it's going through the circle, is there any way I could make the ellipes shorter + go around the circle?

This is the code:

```
pkg load geometry
clf
figure;
t=0:0.01:2*pi;
x=10*cos(t);
y=3*sin(t)/2;
for i=1:12
    hold on;
    q=[x;y];
    e=pi/12*i;
    z=[cos(e) -sin(e);sin(e) cos(e)];
    k=z*q;
    r=k(1,:);
    d=k(2,:);
    plot(r,d);
    axis square;
    pause(1);

endfor
hold on;
drawCircle(0,0,1);
```

This is what mine looks like:

[image: This is what mine looks like]

This is what it is supposed to look like:

[image: This is what it is supposed to look like]

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions in [tag:octave] and [tag:matlab]. Do NOT use both tags, unless you are explicitly asking about differences or similarities between the two languages. They are NOT the same and using both tags needlessly restricts potential answers, as they need to be tested + working in both languages. I presume you use Octave, although the use of `end` is MATLAB syntax. Please specify which of the two you actually use.

Comment: I am using Octave, I thought they were the same, sorry!

Comment: They are rather similar, true, but a 1-on-1 copy is barely ever possible (given the generic `end` in MATLAB vs `endfor`, `endif` etc in Octave) and both languages have various non-overlapping toolboxes. That means that vanilla (without toolboxes) MATLAB v Octave is easily translated (taking the `end` issue into account), but as soon as you use toolboxes it gets complicated.

Comment: why not create a single elipse function with a rotate and translate parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to circle the ellipses' centres as well, they're all centred on the origin now. That means, add a static offset. Something like

```
dist = 1;  % Distance from the origin, change as necessary
x_Offset = dist * cos(e);
y_Offset = dist * sin(e);
plot(r + x_Offset, d + y_Offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and something is here I found which can draw the expected diagramme

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def draw_flower():
    # Create a circular center
    center_theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    x_center = 0.4 * np.cos(center_theta)  # Adjust the radius as necessary
    y_center = 0.4 * np.sin(center_theta)  # Adjust the radius as necessary

    # Plot the circular center
    plt.plot(x_center, y_center, color='blue', label='Center Circle')

    # Create a circle
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    x_circle = np.cos(theta)
    y_circle = np.sin(theta) / 4

    # Plot the outer circle
    #plt.plot(x_circle, y_circle, color='black', label='Outer Circle')

    # Plot vertically aligned ellipses around the circle
    num_petals = 12
    for i in range(num_petals):
        angle = i * (2 * np.pi / num_petals)
        dist = 1.55  # Adjust this distance as necessary
        x_offset = dist * np.cos(angle)
        y_offset = dist * np.sin(angle)

        # Ellipse parameters
        a = 0.4
        b = 0.8

        # Create rotated ellipse
        x_ellipse = x_circle * np.cos(angle) - y_circle * np.sin(angle) + x_offset
        y_ellipse = x_circle * np.sin(angle) + y_circle * np.cos(angle) + y_offset
    
        # Plot the ellipse
        plt.plot(x_ellipse, y_ellipse, label=f'Ellipse {i + 1}')

    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.title('Flower Plot')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

# Call the function to draw the flower
draw_flower()
```